# INSERT into mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So I have 3 tables: `donor`, `blood_type`, `user_account`. I am trying to populate the `donor` table which contains `user_id` and `blood_id`, but there is no join between the `blood_group` and the `user_account` table so I tried this, but it didn't work. Can someone please tell what I am doing wrong? I am very new to php and databases.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root" , "");

    if(!$conn) { 
        die("Cannot connect: "); 
    }

    mysqli_select_db($conn,"blood_bank_project"); 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_account(username, password) VALUES ('$_POST[user]', '$_POST[psw]');";
    $sql .="INSERT INTO donor(first_name,last_name,email_add,gender, birthday, telephone, city, last_donation,user_id, blood_id)VALUES('$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[gender]', '$_POST[Birthday]', '$_POST[Telephone]', '$_POST[city]', '$_POST[lastdonation]')";  
    $sql .="UPDATE donor SET blood_id = (SELECT blood_id from blood_type where blood_group= '$_POST[bloodgroup]');";  
    $sql .="UPDATE donor SET user_id = (SELECT user_id from user_account where username= '$_POST[user]')"; 

    if(mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)){ 
        echo'executed'; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Post code and your output or else you will get down-voted a lot.

Comment: I posted it it is not showing for some reason

Comment: Use the `{ }` code markup tool in the SO editor.

Comment: Is the name of the table `blood_group` or `blood_type`?

Comment: Can you post your HTML form as well?

Comment: The `UPDATE` queries are updating **all** rows of `donor`, since there's no `WHERE` clause to limit the updates.

Comment: blood_type which has 2 columns blood_id and blood_group

Comment: Your question starts with **I have 3 tables donor, blood_group, user_account** Is that a typo?

Comment: There is a where clause in both updates

Comment: You have 10 column names listed in the `INSERT` statement, but only 8 values in the `VALUES` list.

Comment: YES! I will edit the question now

Comment: The `WHERE` clause is just in the `SELECT` subquery, not the `UPDATE` main query.

Comment: You have a "w" before `$sql` in the second `UPDATE` statement. You also have an extra semicolon in the 1st and 3rd `$sql` statement.

Comment: I added WHERE to the update main query. it doesn't work. I think mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql) is returning false since it doesn't echo "executed"

Comment: I read that the multiple sql queries are connected with a semi colon

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: I will. I just need to test the insert first

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `SELECT` clause to produce the values for an `INSERT`. In this case, you can use that to select the appropriate values from the other tables.

```
INSERT INTO donor (user_id, blood_id, first_name,last_name,email_add,gender, birthday, telephone, city, last_donation)
SELECT u.user_id, b.blood_id,
       '$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[gender]', '$_POST[Birthday]', '$_POST[Telephone]', '$_POST[city]', '$_POST[lastdonation]'
FROM user_accounts AS u
CROSS JOIN blood_type AS b
WHERE u.username = '$_POST[user]' AND b.blood_group= '$_POST[bloodgroup]'
```

I also strongly recommend you use prepared queries instead of substituting `$_POST` variables, as the latter subjects you to SQL-injection. I also recommend against using `mysqli_multi_query` -- it's rarely needed and only makes checking for success harder. If you insert into `user_accounts` using a separate query, you can then use `mysqli_insert_id($conn)` to get the `user_id` assigned when you inserted into `user_accounts`, instead of using the above `JOIN`. You can also use the MySQL built-in function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get it.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO user_account(username, password) VALUES (?, ?);") or die("Can't prepare user_account query: " . mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $_POST['user'], $_POST['psw']);
mysqli_execute($stmt);
$stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($conn, "
    INSERT INTO donor (user_id, blood_id, first_name,last_name,email_add,gender, birthday, telephone, city, last_donation)
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), b.blood_id, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
    FROM blood_type AS b
    WHERE b.blood_group= ?") or die ("Can't prepare donor query: " . mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "sssssssss", $_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['gender'], $_POST['Birthday'], $_POST['Telephone'], $_POST['city'], $_POST['lastdonation'], $_POST['bloodgroup']);
mysqli_execute($stmt2);
```

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO user_account(username, password) VALUES ('$_POST[user]', '$_POST[psw]');";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO donor (user_id, blood_id, first_name,last_name,email_add,gender, birthday, telephone, city, last_donation)SELECT u.user_id, b.blood_id, '$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[gender]', '$_POST[Birthday]', '$_POST[Telephone]', '$_POST[city]', '$_POST[lastdonation]'FROM user_accounts AS u CROSS JOIN blood_type AS b WHERE u.username = '$_POST[user]' AND b.blood_group= '$_POST[bloodgroup]'";

(mysqli_multi_query($conn,$sql)

Comment: It doesn't give me an error, it is just not inserting anything to my table

Comment: You have to call `mysqli_error()` to get the error message.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it with prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate your help but it gives me this error

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_bind_param()

Comment: Sorry, it's an alias for `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` that was removed in PHP 5.4.

Comment: it is now giving me a bunch of warnings
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given

Comment: That will happen if `mysqli_prepare()` gets an error, and you didn't check for it. Do you have the `or die` code like in my answer?

Comment: No I added it now! there seems to be a wrong semi colon because it keeps telling that  there is unexpected ';' here 
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO user_account(username, password) VALUES (?, ?);" or die("Can't prepare user_account query: " . mysqli_error($conn));

Comment: I was missing a parenthesis at the end of the first `mysqli_prepare` call.

Comment: Still doesn;t work! Can't prepare donor query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), b.blood_id, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? FROM blo' at line 1

Comment: Had an extra comma in the column list.

Comment: It keeps giving the same error. I cant find the extra comma

Comment: It was between `last_donation` and `)`, right before the place where the error message says that there was a syntax error.

Comment: No errors but no data gets to my table! i have been struggling with this for over a week now!

Comment: Not sure what happened, but I accidentally deleted `mysqli_execute($stmt);`. Are you reading and understanding the code? Didn't you wonder how the first statement would execute without calling `mysqli_execute`? Or are you just blindly copying it without learning how it works?

Comment: I have mysqli_execute() this is my first time working with php prepared statements or php for that matter

Comment: Now I can't figure out what's wrong, unless the username is a duplicate so the insert doesn't work.

Comment: mysql_stmt_bind_param() should be my mysqli_stmt_bind_param() right?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo.

Comment: I fixed that long time ago.. no data gets through! but I really appreciate your help. I will look more into prepared statements

Comment: using prepared statements the user_account table gets populated but not the donor table. Do you have any idea what could be the problem ? Thank u very much

Comment: Is it reporting an error? Are you sure `$_POST['bloodgroup']` has a match in `blood_type.blood_group`?

Comment: This is what I am getting in mysql log
2016-04-15T16:19:47.177655Z 42 [Warning] Warning: Enabling keys got errno 0 on blood_bank_project.donor, retrying

Comment: Yes, I am sure it has a match

Comment: Does it work if you try the query by hand, after filling in all the `?` with the actual values from the form?

Comment: Does it report an error? If it doesn't get an error, and there's a matching row in `blood_type`, I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't perform the insert.

Comment: One row was inserted. but when I tried to insert another row it doesn't work!

Comment: You have to do the inserts in pairs: first insert into `user_account`, then insert into `donor`. Otherwise, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` won't get the ID of the new user account.

Comment: Can you please suggest how can I do this ?

Comment: It's how my code is written. You could add a check that the first one successfully inserted into `user_account` by testing `mysqli_affected_rows($conn)` before you try to insert into `donor`.

Comment: At some point you've got to do your own debugging and programming, you can't really rely on some random from the Internet to do this all for you.

Answer (score 0):

theres a few things wrong with that code snippet:

1. Line 15: You've got a rogue 'w' at the start of the line before your $sql variable
2. All of your $_POST'ed parameters need to be in the format $_POST['parameter'] (Missing quotes, remember to escape your already quoted ones in places)
3. The where clause sub-select query in line 14 is selecting from a table that does not exist (blood_type)

I guess what your trying to achieve is a mapping between 'user_account' and 'donor' of which you may be better either storing a foreign key in the user account table of the 'donor_id', or a matrix/mapping table that links the two together.

The matrix/mapping table would hold the primary key date from both user_account and donor to create your matrix.

You can then get to either table information from the other knowing just one side of the information.

I'd also make sure your escaping your inbound variables in your queries to prevent any SQL Injection attacks ([see here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp))